# Can't connect to remote computer unless I ping it

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ping

Just like the title says really.  We have a computer on our network that monitors the telephone system.  The phones all work fine, no issues there.

We all use software that gives us access to call history, address books etc. but the software is unable to connect.

I used to be able to remote desktop in to the remote computer to check call recording etc. but since installing a new firewall (which, according to our IT "expert" the phone system isn't going through), I can't access this.

All of this changes if we any user opens a command prompt and ping -t.  Then the local software connects and I can connect through remote desktop.  Nothing has changed on the phone system computer so I'm reluctant to think it's anything there.

Short of every single person in the building running the ping -t all day, is there anything else I can try?

And just FYI, our phone company is blaming the IT company, the IT company is blaming the phone system company.  They're not going to be a lot of help.

Comment: Sounds like the new firewall is to blame. Disable it, if problem is gone, blame the IT company and say that it is the firewall and if the firewall is disabled, the problem is gone, so you have deductive reasoning to point the finger towards them.

Comment: Might be a problem with the network architecture. We'll need more details including at least the IP addresses, routers on the path and DHCP servers.

Comment: This site is not for company support. On-topic here is for "personal home networking". That being said, the server fault community deals with business/enterprise questions, but you will have to provide much more technical detail. The bottom line, if you have hired IT "experts" to do a task, and something breaks within your infrastructure, **it is their responsibility to fix it**. If they give your company the run around, causing undue burden or financial loss because of their original actions with the "upgrade", get a lawyer involved. It sounds like they may not have proper qualifications IMO

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the computer is sleeping. The ping acts like a WOL command, so it wakes up. Try changing the settings.

Comment: "Also, this site is not for company support." Try asking this on some other forum, such as Spiceworks.